# MongoDB, Spring JDBC, Dynamic keys, Mapping

Tags: mongodb, dynamic, field, spring-jdbc

I am using spring jdbc and mongoDB. I will have documents as follows.
one is like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f49f05c88c8f2cb8061e12"),
    "temp" : {
        "27" : {
            "59" : "5"
        },
       "28":{
          "0":"0",
          "1":"1"
       }
    },
    "luminosity" : {
        "27" : {
            "59" : "3"
        }
    },
    "identifier" : 753    
}
```

and another might be like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f49f05c88c8f2cb8061e12"),
    "humidity" : {
        "27" : {
            "59" : "5"
        }
    },
    "identifier" : 753    
}
```

So how can i write a mapping class for this. Please help!
I have written something like

```
@Document(collection = "Data")
public class Data {

    private String identifier;


    /**
     * @return the identifier
     */
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    /**
     * @param identifier
     *            the identifierto set
     */
    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier= identifier;
    }


    }
```

How can i write the mappers for other fields? which is dynamic

Comment: Your data structure is weird. Why is there an object called "27" and what does it represent? If you cannot change de datamodel you could just load it as json objects or linkedtreemaps.

Comment: Just wondering whether the below answer is helpful?

Comment: @p.streef the numbers represents minutes/seconds. thank you for the reply

Comment: thank you for the reply @notionquest. It is partially use full. Partially because as i mentioned temp and luminosity is not fixed. May be i have to work on the data model itself

Answer (score 0):

The data structure is unconventional. Normally, the key attribute should not be very dynamic though MongoDB supports it. It may get complicated when you try to write a complex aggregate queries with multiple pipelines.

Anyways, given the above structure, there can be multiple ways to define the document model. I have provided the below solution using simple Java classes (Map and String).

The reason for using simple Map structure is that most of the libraries supports serialization process and Java 8 Lambda functions can be used to iterate and get the values.

**Document class:-**

```
@Document(collection = "weather")
public class Weather {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> temp;

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> luminosity;

    private String identifier;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getLuminosity() {
        return luminosity;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTemp(Map<String, Map<String, String>> temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public void setLuminosity(Map<String, Map<String, String>> luminosity) {
        this.luminosity = luminosity;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }
}
```

**Sample code using Lambda:-**

```
Weather weather = mongoOperations.findById(id, Weather.class);

        System.out.println(weather.toString());
        weather.getTemp().forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println("Temp : " + k + "; Values : " + v);
        });
        weather.getLuminosity().forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println("Temp : " + k + "; Values : " + v);
        });     
        System.out.println(weather.getIdentifier());
```